Guess the next polynoms in the sequence (MO vs. AI :), count anticommuting $F_p$-matrices, P. Hrubeš conjecture
Here is a sequence of polynoms - (presumably) counting N-tuples of ANTI-commuting 2x2 matrices over $F_p, p>2$. (That is just the case of 2x2 matrices, and (surprisingly) it is not so easy to see a pattern ! Compare to commuting matrices where pattern is simple - see MO).
Question: Is there any pattern in the polynom sequence below? What can be the next polynoms ? (Any guess/compute/suggest is highly welcome.)

$p^{5}+3p^{4}-2p^{3}-2p^{2}+p$ : 2-tuples
$p^{6}+3p^{5}+3p^{4}-6p^{3}-3p^{2}+3p$ : 3-tuples
$8p^{6}-5p^{5}+3p^{4}-2p^{3}-10p^{2}+7p$ : 4-tuples
$5p^{7}+11p^{6}-24p^{5}+15p^{4}+5p^{3}-25p^{2}+14p$ : 5-tuples
$6p^{8}+p^{7}+15p^{6}-45p^{5}+31p^{4}+19p^{3}-51p^{2}+25p$ : 6-tuples
$7p^{9}+p^{8}-5p^{7}+20p^{6}-14p^{5}-34p^{4}-29p^{3}+14p^{2}+41p$ : 7-tuples
$8p^{10}+p^{9}-8p^{8}+16p^{7}-30p^{6}+35p^{5}+3p^{4}-10p^{3}+28p^{2}-42p$ : 8-tuples
Unclear, except $f(1)=f(-1)=1, f(3)=1517649, f(5)=434329585$ : 9-tuples
Unclear, except $f(1)=f(-1)=1, f(3)=4990113, f(5)=2403378145$ : 10-tuples
Unclear, except $f(1)=f(-1)=1, f(3)=21327762$ : 11-tuples

(All polynoms satisfy $f(1)=f(-1)=1$, condition $f(1)=1$ is easy to explain, while reason for $f(-1)=1$ - unclear.) Roots are plotted here.
Fun: Mathoverflow vs AI (0:0). Here I tried to get the answer with the top performing AI language model DeepSeekMath https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/spin-off-real-math-problem hopefully MO can be better :)

Context 1: Surprisingly anticommuting matrices appear e.g. in Noga Alon, Kai Zheng paper on Cayley graphs $(Z/2)^d$ which is devoted to the generalization of the breakthrough result by Hao Huang resolving the Sensitivity Conjecture in graph theory. (As Scott Aaronson writes Huang's proof "comes from the book".)
They utilize a result of P.Hrubeš that the maximum possible number of complex invertible anticommuting N by N matrices is $2log_2(N) +1$. So in some sense it is not so easy to find big sets of anticommuting matrices, more precisely you cannot do that when they are invertible, and even more strongly we can expect that big set of anti-commuting matrices should be "quite far" from invertibility. There is the following conjecture by P. Hrubeš which is quantifying that "quite far":
Conjecture (P.Hrubeš): $\sum rank(M_i^2) ≤ O(nlog(n))$ for any set of $n\times n$ anticommuting complex matrices.
Possible approach: One might try to think of the following strategy towards such kind of result. The main problem having big set of anti-commuting matrices - that at certain stage you will need to require it is anti-commuting with itself (or near itself). But $AA+AA=0$ implies $A^2=0$ (p>2). Thus we arrive to the Grassman algebra: anticommuting AND $M_i^2=0$ - but that should not be difficult to count such matrices over $F_p$ - it should follow similar pattern as for commuting matrice (see MO) - at least at 2x2 case the answer seems to be $p^{n+1}+p^{n}-p$ which is only one degree less than the pattern seen from the polynoms above $np^{n+2}+...$. The conjecture is trivially true for Grassman algebra - just all ranks are zeros.  If we would be able to find deformation from the Grassman matrix variety to the  anticommuting variety - such that we would be able to control the ranks - we can hope to the prove the conjecture.
Context 2: Counting anti-commuting matrices is a particular case of counting q-commuting matrices (q=-1) and which is particular case   counting q-Manin matrix variety (just take a rectangular Manin matrices of shape (n,1) i.e. only one column).
Optimistic hope is that for all q (and qp/super/other analogs) counting will be given by polynomials and there will be nice generating functions over matrix sizes $n$ - see results by Yifeng Huang and Anton Mellit MO post for pairs of matrices.
Thanks to MO: The polynomials above were computed with the help of Peter Taylor code appeared in the mathoverflow answer on related question. (My intention was to ask that question right after the question above (2.5 years ago), but looking on these strange polynoms it made me thought that actually counting is not given by polynomials, but now after some more computations I have more optimism).
PS
One may see that the polynoms for 2,3,4 tuples are different from the the subsequent. It might be related to the following there are invertible anti-commuting 2,3 tuples, but there are no such 4-tuples.

MO vs. AI sounds like a modern day "John Henry" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_(folklore) )

It's very unlikely that your numerical approximations are not contaminated by parts of point count which look like $(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}$. If an algebraic variety has a truly polynomial point count, then it puts heavy restriction on the geometry of complex points, see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612668v3

After all, the preimage of $-1$ of a commutator mapping looks not very much unlike Weil-restricted $\mathbb G_m$; that is, group scheme defined by $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, which has exactly $q - (1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}$ points. Various power residue congruences can lead you to "fake" point count polynomials if you're only looking at the prime field $F_p$ and not $F_q$ — because you do not really know degree of (reduced part of) your hypersurface, and hence cannot distinguish between coefficients coming from Langrange interpolation/Jacobsthal sums contributions, and coefficients coming from Hodge numbers.

I think you're going to need values of $f(7)$ to narrow it down to a single guess. With just $f(-1),f(1),f(3),f(5)$ there are three candidate polynomials for the 9-tuples of the form $9x^{11} + O(x^{10})$ and maximum absolute coefficient $9$, which is suspiciously smaller than the maximum absolute coefficients for 5- to 8-tuples.

@PeterTaylor Hi, Peter, thanks for the insight ! Would be happy if you share the polynoms, if possible for 10-tuples also. May be as an answer - would be happy to upvote it . Sometimes it is not unique for n-tuples, but can be unique for n+1 tuples. Calculation for p=7  might be within reach, but not so easy for me. As a note: algebraic computations goes only for 2-tuples, all other n-tuples - is just combinatorial enumeration without solving algebraic equations

The value at $p=-1$ should correspond to the (combinatorial) euler characteristic of the set of real points of the variety

It's not entirely clear to me how much data your guesses are based on, so I present a table with calculated data and guessed polynomials based on that data and the assumption that $f(1) = f(-1) = 1$.
$$\begin{array}{c|rrrrr|l}
\textrm{Dim. tuple} & f(3) & f(5) & f(7) & f(11) & f(13) & \textrm{Guesses for poly} \\
\hline
2 & 417 & 4705 & 23233 & 202081 & 452257 & p^5+3p^4-2p^3-2p^2+p \\
3 & 1521 & 26065 & 173089 & 2290321 & 6012721 & p^6+3p^5+3p^4-6p^3-3p^2+3p \\
4 & 4737 & 110785 & 863233 & 13407361 & 36837697 & 8p^6-5p^5+3p^4-2p^3-10p^2+7p \\
5 & 14289 & 496945 & 5045089 & 113281201 & 358361809 & 5p^7+11p^6-24p^5+15p^4+5p^3-25p^2+14p \\
6 & 44193 & 2536225 & 36499393 & 1325439841 & 5013745633 & 6p^8+p^7+15p^6-45p^5+31p^4+19p^3-51p^2+25p \\
7 & 141297 & 13916305 & 286149409 & 16652411281 & 74810161777 & 7p^9+p^8-6p^7+35p^6-84p^5+56p^4+42p^3-91p^2+41p \\
8 & 461313 & 77844865 & 2264277505 & 208434923521 & 1107983409793 & 8p^{10}+p^9-7p^8+56p^6-140p^5+92p^4+76p^3-148p^2+63p \\
9 & 1517649 & 434329585 & 17762209633 & 2574995104561 & 16182795556369 & 9p^{11}+p^{10}-8p^9+84p^6-216p^5+141p^4+123p^3-225p^2+92p \\
10 & 4990113 & 2403378145 & 137857285825 & 31436323682401 & 233532753660193 & 10p^{12}+p^{11}-9p^{10}+120p^6-315p^5+205p^4+185p^3-325p^2+129p \\
11 & 16337649 & 13184998225 & 1059859907617 & 380035371185041 & 3337003295425969 & 11p^{13}+p^{12}-10p^{11}+165p^6-440p^5+286p^4+264p^3-451p^2+175p \\
12 & 53196417 & 71779197505 & 8083328647681 & 4556998303140481 & 47295113651706817 & 12p^{14}+p^{13}-11p^{12}+220p^6-594p^5+386p^4+362p^3-606p^2+231p \\
13 & 172253649 & 388185983665 & 61233876460897 & 54269703879276721 & 665719485396037969 & 13p^{15}+p^{14}-12p^{13}+286p^6-780p^5+507p^4+481p^3-793p^2+298p \\
14 & 554908065 & 2087405364385 & 461191717267393 & 642536718916721761 & 9315832529969607265 & 14p^{16}+p^{15}-13p^{14}+364p^6-1001p^5+651p^4+623p^3-1015p^2+377p \\
15 & 1779367665 & 11169437347345 & 3456224813772577 & 7569173683597203601 & 129705052899459293425 & 15p^{17}+p^{16}-14p^{15}+455p^6-1260p^5+820p^4+790p^3-1275p^2+469p \\
16 & 5682292737 & 59509281940225 & 25788754164378625 & 88774878097178250241 & 1797955678015106647297 & 16p^{18}+p^{17}-15p^{16}+560p^6-1560p^5+1016p^4+984p^3-1576p^2+575p \\
17 & 18079773777 & 315856939150705 & 191687543576763745 & 1037177302481468389681 & 24826693688627052936337 & 17p^{19}+p^{18}-16p^{17}+680p^6-1904p^5+1241p^4+1207p^3-1921p^2+696p \\
18 & 57338411937 & 1670837408986465 & 1419976657439328961 & 12076140404906226349921 & 341639526320049692470177 & 18p^{20}+p^{19}-17p^{18}+816p^6-2295p^5+1497p^4+1461p^3-2313p^2+833p \\
19 & 181313000433 & 8811950691455185 & 10486983570616069153 & 140176635307767444258961 & 4686916450943683946548273 & 19p^{21}+p^{20}-18p^{19}+969p^6-2736p^5+1786p^4+1748p^3-2755p^2+987p \\
20 & 571832888961 & 46348571786564545 & 77238913776173875201 & 1622672987777336274844801 & 64122747776447821674077761 & 20p^{22}+p^{21}-19p^{20}+1140p^6-3230p^5+2110p^4+2070p^3-3250p^2+1159p \\
21 & 1799181037521 & 243186950694322225 & 567482597908716083041 & 18737432858861663162635441 & 875102561978161296050485201 & 21p^{23}+p^{22}-20p^{21}+1330p^6-3780p^5+2471p^4+2429p^3-3801p^2+1350p \\
\end{array}$$
Note that we disagree on data for 11-tuples, and guessed polys from 7-tuples.
We appear to have the recurrence $$f_n(p) = (2p+4)f_{n-1}(p) - (p^2 +8p + 6)f_{n-2}(p) + (4p^2 + 12p + 4)f_{n-3}(p) - (6p^2 + 8p + 1)f_{n-4}(p) + (4p^2 + 2p)f_{n-5}(p) -p^2 f_{n-6}(p)$$
Source code used to generate the data.

Wow ! Thanks a lot ! So there seems to be pattern for the first 3 coefs: n,1,-(n-1) ... but the other coefficients look surprising .... I listed p which I was able to check in the table of my notebook https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/count-nilpotent-polynom-matrices  - but yours cover more p , for high tuples , than mine.  Very interesting

How did you calculate that ? –

Cliques in a graphs ?! how that comes up ? what graph ?

The vertices are $2\times 2$ graphs over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, with edges between matrices which anti-commute and loops on matrices which anti-commute with themselves.

I've managed to significantly optimise the calculations to the point that I can get data for $p=13$, $n=21$, and that gives enough polynomials to conjecture a recurrence which implies the desired g.f. I haven't attempted to write the g.f. explicitly because I suspect it's quite large. Edit: although actually the denominator factors nicely as $(z-1)^4 (pz-1)^2$ so maybe not.

Yes, even extending back to $f_0(p) = 1, f_1(p) = p^4$ we don't get a clean numerator. $1 + (p^4-2p-4)z + (-p^5 - p^4 - 2p^3 - p^2 + 9p + 6)z^2 + (p^5 + p^4 + 6p^3 - p^2 - 13p - 4)z^3 + (-p^7 + 5p^6 - 7p^5 - p^4 + p^3 - 2p^2 + 9p + 1)z^4 + (p^8 - 4p^7 + 4p^6 + 2p^5 - 5p^4 + 4p^3 - p^2 - 2p)z^5$

Thanks again ! Please take a look on https://mathoverflow.net/q/470025/10446 - may be yours comments on "graph/cliques" can be applied in that generality ? Also may be rationality of generation function ?

It is also very interesting that we can see that number of non zero terms of polynoms - stabilizes - at most 9 non-zero terms for all n . That is similar to the more simple case of the commuting matrices - https://mathoverflow.net/q/469596/10446 , but the differnce is that here coefficients depend "n" - while in commuting/Manin cases it was more simple - no such dependence when n is large enough

Thanks again ! Here is related question - may be there is also similar recurrence relation - but no so sure: https://mathoverflow.net/q/470969/10446

Dear Peter would you be so kind to look: https://mathoverflow.net/q/483966/10446

It is possible to calculate the general formula for the polynomials $f_n$.
Note that:

If $AB+BA=0$ and $B\neq 0$ then either $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ or $\operatorname{tr} A=0$.
If $A\neq 0$ has nonzero trace and an eigenvalue equals to $0$, then it is conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. If $B\neq 0$ anticommutes with such $A$ then under the same conjugation $B$ would be of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$. The only matrix anticommuting with both $A$ and $B$ is the zero matrix
If $\operatorname{tr}A = \operatorname{tr}B=0$, then $A,B$ anticommutes if and only if $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=0$. On the subspace of 2x2 matrices with zero trace, the bilinear form $A,B\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ can be diagonalized to $(2, 2, -2)$. It has $p+1$ isotropic lines and no totally isotropic planes.

Therefore, each n-tuple of anticommuting 2x2 matrices, after removing occurances of the zero matrix, is exactly one of the following types:

No nonzero matrices. Number of n-tuples: $1$.
Exactly one nonzero matrix. Number of n-tuples: $n(p^4-1)$.
Two anticommuting nonzero matrices, each with nonzero traces. Number of n-tuples: $\binom n2 (p+1)p(p-1)^2$.
$k$ nonzero matrices with trace $0$, which anticommutes and nonisotropic according to the bilinear form above, for $k=2,3$. Number of n-tuples:

for $k=2$: $\binom n2 p(p-1)^2(p^2-1)$
for $k=3$: $\binom n3 p(p-1)^3(p^2-1)$


$k$ nonzero scalar multiples of the same isotropic matrix with trace $0$, for $k\geq 2$. Number of n-tuples: $\binom nk (p+1)(p-1)^k$
$k-1$ nonzero scalar multiples of the same isotropic matrix with trace $0$, and another nonisotropic trace-$0$ matrix anticommuting with the previous one, for $k\geq 2$. Number of n-tuples: $\binom nk k (p+1)(p-1)^{k-1}(p^2-p)$

Summing it all, we get
\begin{multline}
f_n(p) =
1
+ n(p^4-1)
+ \binom n2 (p+1)p(p-1)^2
+ \binom n2 p(p-1)^2(p^2-1)
+ \binom n3 p(p-1)^3(p^2-1)
+ \sum_{k=2}^n \binom nk (p+1)(p-1)^k
+ \sum_{k=2}^n \binom nk k (p+1)(p-1)^{k-1}(p^2-p)
=\\=
1
+ n(p^4-1)
+ \binom n2 (p+1)p(p-1)^2
+ \binom n2 p(p-1)^2(p^2-1)
+ \binom n3 p(p-1)^3(p^2-1)
+(p+1)\left(p^n - 1 - n(p-1)\right)
+(p+1)(p^2-p)\left( np^{n-1} - n \right)
\end{multline}

Great answer ! Thanks a lot ! Does your analysis support/make more precise Hrubes conjecture - i.e. giving precise constant for Cnlog(n) for that particular 2x2 case  ? If we consider Grassman matrices: impose additional relation M^2=0 - the counting seems to be  $p^{n+1}+p^n−p$ - does it follow from one of items in your analysis ?

@AlexanderChervov  The Grassman matrices are exactly those matrices I called "isotropic", so the n-tuples using only them are mostly counted by item 5.

@AlexanderChervov For Hrubes conjecture, it follows that for the 2x2 case the maximal value of $\sum \operatorname{rank}(M_i^2)$ is $6$, given by case 4 with $k=3$.
